# Can a Webrtc client use UDP messages from a server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I was learning about webrtc and was wondering that if a Node.js server already knew the ip and port of a browser client, is there a way to send UDP messages to that client and read them via javascript with webrtc (or another method)? I know that browsers don't allow sending UDP messages because of security concerns, but it would be interesting if a browser is able to read UDP messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this isn’t possible today. There is a RFC for [raw sockets](https://github.com/WICG/raw-sockets) but it isn’t implemented.

I would run a WebRTC implementation on your server and use the DataChannel. SCTP can be run in unreliable/unordered mode. It is really easy like [this](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/tree/master/examples/data-channels)

There is also [WebTransport](https://w3c.github.io/webtransport/) but is just an RFC as well.